# CSS exclude custom header from specific pages when printing

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

I'm trying to exclude a custom header from the first page and last page of a PDF (as they are cover pages and should not contain the company header) when printing using `@Media print`

I've seen a couple of people suggesting to use `display: none` for `@page :first` however this does not work. It doesnt appear to be valid CSS either as intellisense doesn't pick it up.

So, I have the following CSS which adds the header to each page when trying to print:

```
@media print {

   header, footer {
   position: fixed;
   }
                    
   header {
      top: 0;
   }

   footer {
      bottom: 0;
   }
}
```

And I would like to exclude this header from the first and last pages. I have tried adding this to the `print` block:

```
@page :first {
   header { display: none; }
}
```

But as I said, it doesn't appear to be valid CSS. Any suggestions?

Comment: If there's a separate header & footer element for each page you could use first-child & last-child selectors. But there might be one header & footer element which are applied to every page, in which case you would need to handle that before the pdf is output rather than with css.

Comment: Looks like you can only change a few attributes with @page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page. Are you able to modify the HTML? Inserting a hide-on-print helper class may work for you.

Comment: It's just the one header & footer element which is repeated on-print so unfortunately I can't grab a specific header/footer using a selector. I think my only chance was if I could somehow select it with @page but I guess it can't be done with this implementation.

Comment: How are you generating the pdf? [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) has some decent built-in options. You could perhaps use javascript's `window.onbeforeprint`. Or use z-index to mask the header/footer on the first and last pages